# Get Line Number of Exception from Parameterized Action

Tags: c#, design-patterns, exception

Whenever I pass an `Action` as a parameter that is declared inline I don't get the correct line number when an exception is thrown.  For example, if I declare this function:

```
public static void Do(Action action)
{
    //do some things
    action();
    //do some things
}
```

And then call it like this:

```
Helper.Do(() => {
   int x = 1;
   x++;
   x = x / 0;
   x--;
});
```

The exception that returns will reference the line `Helper.Do(() => {` which doesn't tell me which line threw the actual error.  Is there a way to retrieve the correct line number while still using this pattern?

Comment: Is `Helper.Do` inside a `try catch`?

Comment: I can put it inside a `try catch` or even let the entire application crash, the stack trace in the exception will point to the `Helper.Do` line number in both cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested your code and I get the exact line number where the `Exception` occurred. This was my test code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            Helper.Do(() => {
                int x = 1;
                x++;
                x = x / 0;
                x--;
            });
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
            throw;
        }
}
```

`e.Message = "Attempted divide by zero"`

`e.StackTrace =    at ConsoleApplication1.Program.<>c.<Main>b__1_0() in C:\test\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs:line 46
   at ConsoleApplication1.Helper.Do(Action action) in C:\test\test\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\Helper.cs:line 14
   at ConsoleApplication1.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\test\test\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs:line 43`

Line 46 of stacktrace is `x = x / 0;`

Comment: Ah ok, you got it.  I figured out that what I was doing was rethrowing from inside the `Do` method which appears to cause the behavior I was seeing.  Thank you